# Select all records from table A, even if one or more of it's ID(i.e FK) not present in table B

Tags: mysql, select, join

First of all, I know heading sounds a bit confusing and I am sorry for that. I couldn't find words to articulate myself exactly in a sentence.

So here is what I am trying to do :

A simple search box where user types in a name and gets autosuggestion like in google.

My first table('users') is like this :

```
  Table 'users':

   Id(PK)     name   email
    10        max    max@max.com
    20        john   john@john.com
    30        jack   jack@jack.com
    40        jill   jill@jill.com
```

And second table('pictures') like this :

```
  Table 'pictures':

   Id    user_id(FK)   profilepic          iscurrent
    1    10            abc.jpg             1
    2    20            sds.jpg             0
    3    30            asdasd.jpg          1
    4    20            sdsdff.jpg          1
```

Now when users start typing name say `"joh"`, he will see `"john + john's email + john's picture"` in suggestions .

This is how I am implementing it now :

```
SELECT users.name, users.email, pictures.profilepic
FROM pictures 
INNER JOIN users 
ON pictures.user_id=users.id 
WHERE pictures.is_current = 1 
AND users.name LIKE '%joh%' OR email LIKE '%joh%' 
ORDER BY users.id 
ASC LIMIT 5;
```

The problem is that it selects only records which have a FK in second table('pictures')

but I want users to see all records matching the name they entered even if that user doesn't have a profile picture .

Hope you've understood the problem.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: USE left join i think it solves your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do a select from the users to the pictures using the left join instead of inner join. It should look like this:

```
SELECT users.name, users.email, pictures.profilepic
FROM users
LEFT JOIN pictures
ON pictures.user_id=users.id 
WHERE pictures.is_current = 1 
AND users.name LIKE '%joh%' OR email LIKE '%joh%' 
ORDER BY users.id ASC
LIMIT 5;
```

Or, you leave it like that but use right join instead.

```
SELECT users.name, users.email, pictures.profilepic
FROM pictures
RIGHT JOIN users
ON pictures.user_id=users.id 
WHERE pictures.is_current = 1 
AND users.name LIKE '%joh%' OR email LIKE '%joh%' 
ORDER BY users.id ASC
LIMIT 5;
```

Comment: Sorry but I ran into another problem. It works fine if I remove `WHERE pictures.is_current = 1`,  but it's not returning all result from 'users' table if I include this line.

Answer (score 1):

You should use left join instead of inner join, this will return you all the rows from the table: users. Even if a user doesn't have a picture will also be listed.

Comment: Still the same result, it does not selects all values from 'users' table. But only those which have a FK in 'pictures' table.

Comment: Yes you were right, I used LEFT JOIN and worked well. thanks.

Comment: Sorry but I ran into another problem. It works fine if I remove `WHERE pictures.is_current = 1`, but it's not returning all result from 'users' table if I include this line

Comment: @kamronshaw : this is a valid scenario because by adding a where clause you are filtering the result. Hence, the results are filtered by pictures.is_current =1 and so the users who doesn't have pictures are being filtered out.

Solution :    WHERE (pictures.is_current =1 OR pictures.is_current is NULL) 

This will list the users with picture with is_current = 1 AND also the user who doesn't have any picture.